# adding HTML between user inputs using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and have what's probably a simple question. Here I'm trying to create a list where a user types something into input fields #newtask and #neighborhood then by clicking #addrest these values are added to the page. What I'd like to do is separate #newtask and #neighborhood in the DOM by adding HTML with content `" in "` so on the page it reads: `"(user's input in #newtask) in (user's input in #neighborhood)"`. Right now it just adds the two inputs with no space in between them. How do I add this HTML using jQuery?

Current code:

```
$("#addrest").click(function() {
    create_task($("#newtask").val() + $("#neighborhood").val());
    $("#newtask").val("");
    $("#neighborhood").val("");
});
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that create_task needs to be included in here because it's a function that (earlier in the code) adds these user inputs to the interface and also syncs it to storage using JSON.

Comment: try adding `+ " " +` instead of just `+` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`.after`](https://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$("#newtask").val("");
$("#newtask").after(" in ");
$("#neighborhood").val("");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/2jsGu/)**

Answer (score 0):

try to do somthing like this:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addrest").click(function () {
            create_task($("#newtask").val(), $("#neighborhood").val());
            $("#newtask").val("");
            $("#neighborhood").val("");
        });
    });
    function create_task(a, b) {
        $("#result").html("user\'s input in #newtask " + a + " <br /> user\'s input in #neighborhood " + b);

    }
   </script>
```

And suppose you want to display your output in a div having id "result":

```
 <div id="result"></div>
```

In this way you can get your desire output. You can update this according to your requirement.